# Declaring a KeyEvent

Tags: java, applet, jframe, keyevent

I would like to make a game where a square goes around with the arrow keys, but I am unable to Declare it
see moveIt

```
public void moveIt(/*Won't work here, since its started on run method*/) {


 KeyEvent evt=/*???*/; //how do i declare this keyevent?


 switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            myY += 5;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            myY -= 5;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            myX -= 5;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            myX += 5;
            break;
    }



}
```

`myX` and `myY` are coordinates for the rectangle to use in another method.

By the way, I'm new to java. Its my first programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you **don't** declare a `KeyEvent`. The `KeyEvent` is generated by the user pressing a key. That event is then picked up by a `KeyListener`, where you place your logic to handle the key event.

```
public class MyClass extends JPanel implements KeyListener
{
    // Add your intialization code here

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        switch (evt.getKeyCode())
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                myY += 5;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                myY -= 5;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                myX -= 5;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                myX += 5;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html). You've missed a trick, and reviewing the fundamentals will likely put you back on course.

Comment: But how will i call this method i another method?

Comment: Did you read the tutorial? Read it. The whole point of a KeyListener is that it listens for key events! You don't call this method directly at all. You need to read the tutorial right now because what you think is happening is clearly not what is happening.

Comment: JFrame isn't focusable for KeyEvents